# Why the continue_game is not False in my Python code

Tags: python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to create a tic-tac-toe game. The most major problem right now is that the continue game cannot set to be False after a row, a column or a diagonal has won. It also cannot print out who won. By the way, how to switch players between 'X' and 'O'.

In addition, can this be simplified?

```
    if pos_y == 0 and pos_x == 0:
      board[5] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 0 and pos_x == 1:
      board[6] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 0 and pos_x == 2:
      board[7] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 1 and pos_x == 0:
      board[9] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 1 and pos_x == 1:
      board[10] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 1 and pos_x == 2:
      board[11] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 2 and pos_x == 0:
      board[13] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 2 and pos_x == 1:
      board[14] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 2 and pos_x == 2:
      board[15] = 'X'
```

```
def main():
  print('----------------------------------')
  print('Starting new Meta Tic Tac Toe game')
  print('----------------------------------')
  board = [' ','0','1','2',
           '0',' ',' ',' ',
           '1',' ',' ',' ',
           '2',' ',' ',' ']
  continue_game = True
  winner = None
  current_player = 'X'
  def display_board():
    print(board[0]+' '+board[1]+'   '+board[2]+'   '+board[3])
    print(board[4]+' '+board[5]+' | '+board[6]+' | '+board[7])
    print('------------')
    print(board[8]+' '+board[9]+' | '+board[10]+' | '+board[11])
    print('------------')
    print(board[12]+' '+board[13]+' | '+board[14]+' | '+board[15])


  def play_game():
    display_board()
    while continue_game:
      switch_turn(current_player)
      game_over()
      flip_player()
    if winner == 'X' or winner == 'O':
      print(winner+'won')
    elif winner == None:
      print('Tie')

  def switch_turn(player):
    pos_y = input('Player 1, please enter a row: ')
    pos_y = int(pos_y)
    pos_x = input('Player 1, please enter a column: ')
    pos_x = int(pos_x)

    if pos_y == 0 and pos_x == 0:
      board[5] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 0 and pos_x == 1:
      board[6] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 0 and pos_x == 2:
      board[7] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 1 and pos_x == 0:
      board[9] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 1 and pos_x == 1:
      board[10] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 1 and pos_x == 2:
      board[11] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 2 and pos_x == 0:
      board[13] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 2 and pos_x == 1:
      board[14] = 'X'
    if pos_y == 2 and pos_x == 2:
      board[15] = 'X'

    display_board()

  def game_over():
    win()
    tie()

  def win():
    global winner
    row_winner = rows()
    columns_winner = columns()
    diagonals_winner = diagonals()
    if row_winner:
      winner = row_winner
    elif columns_winner:
      winner = columns_winner
    elif diagonals_winner:
      winner = diagonals_winner
    else:
      winner = None
    return

  def rows():
    global continue_game
    row_1 = board[5] == board[6] == board[7] != ' '
    row_2 = board[9] == board[10] == board[11] != ' '
    row_3 = board[13] == board[14] == board[15] != ' '
    if row_1 or row_2 or row_3:
      continue_game = False
    if row_1:
      return board[5]
    elif row_2:
      return board[9]
    elif row_3:
      return board[13]
    return

  def columns():
    global continue_game
    column_1 = board[5] == board[9] == board[13] != ' '
    column_2 = board[6] == board[10] == board[14] != ' '
    column_3 = board[7] == board[11] == board[15] != ' '
    if column_1 or column_2 or column_3:
      continue_game = False
    if column_1:
      return board[5]
    elif column_2:
      return board[6]
    elif column_3:
      return board[7]
    return

  def diagonals():
    global continue_game
    diagonal_1 = board[5] == board[10] == board[15] != ' '
    diagonal_2 = board[7] == board[10] == board[13] != ' '
    if diagonal_1 or diagonal_2:
      continue_game = False
    if diagonal_1:
      return board[5]
    elif diagonal_2:
      return board[7]
    return

  def tie():
    return

  def flip_player():
    return

  play_game()
main()
```

Comment: Because it doesn't get set to false?

Comment: i just can't make the game stopped...

Comment: Break the issue down and improving text style

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a class because it is easier to organize and to keep track of variables.

```
class TicTacToe:

    def new_game(self):
        self.board = [[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
        self.player = 'X'
        print('----------------------------------')
        print('Starting new Meta Tic Tac Toe game')
        print('----------------------------------')
        self.play()

    def play(self):
        r = int(input(f'Player {self.player}, please enter a row: '))
        c = int(input(f'Player {self.player}, please enter a column: '))
        if self.board[r][c] == ' ':
            self.board[r][c] = self.player
        else:
            print('Slot is taken')
            self.play()
            return
        print('\n---------\n'.join(' | '.join(row) for row in self.board))
        if self.game_over():
            print('Tie game') if self.player is None else print(self.player + ' wins!')
            if input('New game (Y/N): ').upper() == 'Y':
                self.new_game()
        else:
            self.player = 'O' if self.player == 'X' else 'X'
            self.play()
        return

    def game_over(self):
        if (any(set(row) == {self.player} for row in self.board) or
            any(set(col) == {self.player} for col in zip(*self.board)) or
            set(self.board[i][i] for i in range(3)) == {self.player} or
            self.board[0][2] == self.board[1][1] == self.board[2][0] == self.player):
            return True
        elif not any(' ' in row for row in self.board):
            self.player = None
            return True
        return False

TicTacToe().new_game()
```